# Why didn't they use an article ("The" or "A") in this sentence?

Tags: articles

Why didn't they use an article ("The" or "A") before "*newspaper*" in this sentence from *Jacqueline Wilson's Happy Holidays*?

```
Mum made us put newspaper down first so that we wouldn't get piles.
```

I Think it should be *"put **the** newspaper".

Full source [**here**.](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=iGcZBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=%22Mum%20made%20us%20put%20newspaper%20down%20first%20so%20that%20we%20wouldn%27t%20get%20piles%22&source=bl&ots=Im3G_Gqubm&sig=93fHTmb4zWQ4yWn21Z_sStn5WRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiggqa_89LcAhVYfysKHdfDDdIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Mum%20made%20us%20put%20newspaper%20down%20first%20so%20that%20we%20wouldn't%20get%20piles%22&f=false)

Comment: I don't understand the intent of the sentence. Can you please elaborate? How does putting newspaper down first stop people from getting piles, whether medical or mountainous?

Comment: Please have a look at the original source, I don't understand the piles thing too :) Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the medical sort. I agree with Michael Harvey's answer. By the way, it would help for you to quote the whole paragraph. If/when you edit your answer, use ">" at the start of the line for the block quote. The back-tick quotes don't automatically produce line breaks (if you're using the buttons, use the double-quote icon rather than the braces).

Comment: It’s a common belief that sitting on a cold/hard step or surface will give you piles (hemorrhoids). I haven’t seen any evidence of causation or even correlation, and that’s what I told my mother (she still warned me whenever I sat on the back step).

Answer (score 5):

'Newspaper' is being used in your example as a non-count (mass noun) which does not need a preceding article.

> 3. uncountable noun
>
> Newspaper consists of pieces of old newspapers, especially when they
>   are being used for another purpose such as wrapping things up.
>
> He found two pots, each wrapped in newspaper.

[Newspaper (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/newspaper)